# Missing template for Db context generator for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have Vs2010  ultimate. I installed asp.net mvc 4 and EF 5 that was part of it.

There is no db context generator template for EF 5 for visual studio 2010. Only for  the RC of the next version.

Short of installing vs 2012. What are my options?

Comment: DbContext is for EF 4.1 and later. Suggest you get the latest (4.3.x)  with Nuget

Answer (score 3):

You can find the generators in VS gallery - [EF 5.x DbContext Generator for C#](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/da740968-02f9-42a9-9ee4-1a9a06d896a2) or [EF 5.x DbContext Generator for C# Web Sites](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d01a981-91b8-492c-b42c-c771c3f31e03); both  are intended for VS2012 but perhaps you'll be able to make them work with VS2010.

Comment: not me. I have been using Linq to SQL.  Linq to SQL has been in legacy limbo for the last few years so I am finally making the transition to EF. I am an EF tyro or newbie.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternate way to accomplish this:

- In the **Add New Item** dialog box, at the section on the left where you choose the type of template, click on **Online Templates** and then perform a search for what you need.
- In this case you would search for **DbContext Generator**, you will get many listings that look like **EF 5.x DbContext Generator for C#** or **EF 4.x DbContext Generator for C#**. Select the appropriate version based on the version of EF you have installed.

This is intended for and works right from within VS 2010 so you don't have to man handle anything. You should be all set.

Cheers!